# Postgres JOIN choice after VACUUM

Tags: postgresql

I recently did a major version update from 11.10 to 15.2. Afterwards one query performed very poorly (like 100x worse than before). I established that I simply needed a VACUUM ANALYZE to clear it up. But I was curious about what had happened and dug down.

When I finally got a minimal example I noticed the before doing even just a VACUUM all the joins listed in explain were Hash Left join. After the vacuum all the joins listed were Nested Loop Left Join.

No data had changed and there were only two rows in the database, each in separate tables. There are four other tables referenced in the query that are empty. The only dead tuples are 1 in pg_authid, 7 in pg_class and 4 in pg_database.

I was both curious why it would have chosen a Hash Left Join before VACUUM and then Nested Loop Left Join after. And why was the impact so drammatic (about 20x slower than before a vacuum in minimal example)

I have included the query below and there are a few other curiosities I came across that I assume are just caching (e.g. there are two unused fields on datatag; if I remove them there is no performance hit so I assume it is rolling over some size threshold). Date is a date, text is a text, physical_width and unit_scale are reals, datatagid and assetid are uuid. The datatagid also references back from all other tables to the datatag table.

```
SELECT 
        datatag_date.date,
        datatag_text.text,
        datatag_imagedetect.physical_width,
        (ARRAY(SELECT assetid FROM datatag_extra_file WHERE datatag_extra_file.datatagid = datatag.datatagid)) AS assets,
        datatag_model.unit_scale
    FROM datatag
    LEFT OUTER JOIN datatag_date ON datatag.datatagid = datatag_date.datatagid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN datatag_text ON datatag.datatagid = datatag_text.datatagid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN datatag_imagedetect ON datatag.datatagid = datatag_imagedetect.datatagid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN datatag_model ON datatag.datatagid = datatag_model.datatagid
```

Comment: Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output all we can do is guess wildly. Perhaps `VACUUM` updated the visibility map, so that an index-only scan could perform as it should. Perhaps you just left `random_page_cost` at too high a value.